# Permissions needed for calling REST API

Tags: rest-api

I am working on an assignment where I need to expose `Contact` data to a webservice via `REST API`. I was able to get the `REST API` call working thru Postman/SoapUI only when the Profile has the `View All` permission checked for the `Contact` of the running user. My objective is to restrict the access for the webservice to specific fields on Contacts, not on all fields. Is there anyway I can get this done without having to give the `View All` permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Permissions and the Salesforce REST API

The Salesforce REST API respects field-level security and record-level security. In order for you to obtain access to a specific Contact record, the user account under which you authenticate to Salesforce must be able to see it.

"View All" permission controls record-level visibility. A context user with View All permission ignores the effects of sharing rules and Organization-Wide Defaults, meaning it can see every Contact in the system at the *record* level. It does *not* mean that every *field* on the Contact is visible.

Field visibility is controlled by Field-Level Security. You can configure this on the Profile and/or assigned Permission Sets for the user under which you authenticate. That user will only be able to obtain data for the fields for which the user has Read access, on Contacts which Record-Level Security allows them to see.

You can leave the View All permission turned on if it meets your specific record-level visibility needs while restricting access to individual fields with Field-Level Security.

You can illustrate this FLS enforcement for yourself using Workbench. For example, if you remove FLS for yourself from the `Industry` field on Account, and then use REST Explorer to issue the following GET request:

> /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/001360000XXXXXXXXX?fields=Name,Id,Industry

You will get back

> SELECT Name,Id,Industry FROM Account ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:16 No such column 'Industry' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names

Because you don't have permission to see that field. This applies even to a System Administrator, who has Modify All Data permission - which trumps View All.

### Custom API Classes

The material below is less relevant to your situation, since you explained that you are using the native Salesforce API directly rather than writing your own API class.

Because Apex runs in system mode, you need to manually enforce CRUD and FLS based on the permissions of the current running user in your Apex REST API classes. The document [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS) actually has an example just for your use case, "CRUD and FLS Enforcement in Apex Web Services" (it's written with SOAP web services in mind, but REST would be the same logic).

Read enforcement looks like this, from the linked document:

```
  webservice static String getContactPhone (Id contactId) {
        // Check if the user has read access on the Phone field
        if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Phone.isAccessible()){
          return null;
        }

        return [SELECT Phone FROM Contact WHERE            
                Id=:contactId].Phone;                                                      
      }
```

Another critical piece to consider is the sharing model declared on your REST service class. If you're seeing a need to have the Contact View All permission on your authenticated user, you probably have declared your class `with sharing` or `inherited sharing`. That's good, in most situations, because it applies your org's sharing rules to queries performed by the class. In select use cases, you might want to use `without sharing`, but it's better to permission that level of access at the user level.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't have any wrapper class in Salesforce and hence I cannot enforce CRUD in code. The service is directly calling the REST API by providing the contact Id as /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/{salesforce_id_of_contact}?fields=Id,Name. The problem is I cannot get this REST API working without giving the "View All" permission on contact object. If I uncheck and just leave the "Read" permission, it still doesn't work. So, it appears that I cannot enforce FLS in this case, correct?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You are calling the Salesforce REST API directly, *not* writing your own REST API in Apex. I will update my answer.

Comment: again thanks for updating the answer. Without the "View All" permission, the REST API is not working for me. With the "View All" and have the FLS checked on Id and Name, I assume the webservice user cannot see any info other Id and Name, correct? However, this is not the case. The webservice user is able to see all fields on Contact even though all contact fields are not visible under his profile. Only Id and Name are checked for 'Read' access.

Comment: Where are you configuring the FLS? That is not how enforcement works on API access (I added an example in my answer).

Comment: View All is separate from FLS. If you need View All, it's because Record-Level Security isn't allowing your user to see that whole Contact.

Comment: The user is assigned to a 'Basic User' profile which has permissions on 'API Enabled' and 'Call Apex Rest Services' and everything else is unchecked. I created a permission set for the webservice user and under the Contact Object, I have the following fields checked. 'Read', 'View All', 'Id', 'Name'. Without the 'View All', I get 'The requested resource not found' error. With 'View All', FLS is not enforced. The webservice is able to query on any fields on Contact even though Id and Name are only given the Read permission.

Comment: Does the Basic User profile *itself* have field permissions on Contact? The Permission Set is additive to the Profile; it does not override existing FLS.

Comment: No, As I mentioned in my earlier post, the Basic User Profile does not have any access to any Objects. Only the 'API Enabled' 'Call Apex Rest Services' are enabled.

Comment: you are correct. Though at the profile level, the checkboxes against contact are not checked, when I click on the Contact object itself and look inside, all the fields are checked by default. It is the same case for other objects under this profile as well. I may have to run a data loader update on the FieldPermissions object to reset the permissions. Let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: That's definitely the issue here. Glad we were able to resolve that.